# Where do Adobe AIR applications cache video files?

Tags: streaming, mediaplayer

I have various *players* that play videos from websites, I want to know where those videos are cached.
Because it's AIR, I suppose it's caching in a particular place, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mac OS X, all applications store theire cache files in one place:

> /Users/yourusername/Library/Caches

There you can find the Adobe caches, and Adobe Air cache files.

Comment: By all you mean absolutely all ? do all AIR app use the same "AIR" folder or their own, like other apps ?

Comment: I misunderstand your question: All Apps use their own folders. But they are all in the "Caches-Folder" in Mac OS X.